# Cannot set up phpmyadmin

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up phpmyadmin in docker but getting the error

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    networks:
      - ekb-urist
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ekb-urist
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=ekb-urist
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: ekb-urist
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      PMA_HOST: mysql
networks:
  ekb-urist:
    driver: bridge
```

mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

Comment: When this info happen? If possible, simple question with remove some unused service which not result in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
networks:
  - ekb-urist
```

into `phpmyadmin:` section in your `docker-compose.yaml`